# Meteor third party script doenst work

Tags: meteor

I want to add a third party Javascript File.

E.g. When I put it in folder /public/test.js or /lib/test.js or /client/test.js

```
function testLoad(){

   alert("something");
}
```

I see the scripts getting loaded but when I try to run them through

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

   testLoad();

}
```

I get the following error

> ReferenceError: testLoad is not defined

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your file in `client/compatibility`:

> Some JavaScript libraries only work when placed in the client/compatibility subdirectory. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. This means that each top-level var defines a global variable. In addition, these files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.

http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

The problem is that `function functionName(){ <code> }` wont be a globally defined function (unless you put it in the `client/compatibility` folder).